# webpack tree shaking with Lazy loading question

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, ecmascript-2016, tree-shaking

all, I'm new to Webpack. Currently, I'm facing a question with webpack tree shaking. In CommonJS, webpack cannot do tree shaking because of the `require` syntax. For example, a program can import packages from below ways but tree shaking cannot be worked,

```
var a;
if(condition){
    a = require('module1');
}else{
    a = require('module2');
}
```

Then, tree shaking is based on `import` static syntax from ES6 modules, package cannot be imported dynamically.

However, in es7, there is a dynamic way to load modules by **lazy loading** `import (module)`. So, my question is can tree shaking still work if the program contains lazy loading syntax, if webpack can do that, how is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no compiler/bundler supports tree shaking dynamically imported modules. Webpack 5 might be slightly better in removing unused code inside dynamically loaded bundles.

You can however do it the old way; Create two html sites, have a shared bundle of JS and page-specific bundle, and just link to the other page.